# How to match last instance of token in pattern regex?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following regex `^.*?((\yo\b.*?(cut me:)[\s\S]*))$` - with `ms` flags

[regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/pE8gK4)

As you can see it matched the first instance of "yo".  I want it to match the very last instance of "yo" that is closest to "cut me".  I need this to be multiline-dotall.

How can I mod the regex so that I get the following matched output?

Output (currently matches in red):

```
yo keep this here

Keep this here


yo 
blah, blah, blah cut me:

Allof this here should be deleted
```

Exptected Output (what I want to match in red):

```
yo 
blah, blah, blah cut me:

Allof this here should be deleted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe don't make first `.*?` reluctant.

```
^.*((\yo\b.*?(cut me:)[\s\S]*))$
```

seems to solve your problem.

Also since you are using `dotall` flag then maybe change `[\s\S]` to `.`